# Current limit using MOSFET

Tags: current-measurement, current-limiting, shunt

I am driving a 24V DC Motor which can draw up to 30A and I would like to incorporate some over current/short circuit protection. As such I am planning to place a shunt resistor and power MOSFET(IRF1405) after my load to switch it off if excessive current across the shunt is detected. This is illustrated in the figure below.

Where I am stuck is what circuitry can be used in place of the block labeled "Some IC?". Ideally I would like to use a single chip solution however I am unable to find something suitable. What is a good solution I can use, and what effect would such a configuration have on inrush current?

Some things i have found are the INA300 however this output signal was never designed to drive the gate of a MOSFET or the LTC4361 which is ideal but not suited for a 24V application.

[image: Figure 1 - Planned Circuit layout]

Comment: Do you want your MOSFET to behave as a simple on/off over-current switch or as a current limit control which limits the maximum current?

Comment: simple on/off will be sufficient. However current control limiting maximum current would be even better!

Comment: A current limiter is not going to be easy to implement. A current limiter works by dropping voltage across the mosfet and dissipating the power as heat. If you current limit at 30A and drop just 1V across the mosfet you have 30W of heat to get rid of. That needs a big heatsink. You then have to add extra protection circuitry around the mosfet to protect it against over temperature, which is getting complicated. An over-current trip is easier to implement. Even easier is a simple resetable fuse.

Comment: What if the gate is instead driven by a pwm to limit the current rather then dropping the voltage accross the mosfet?

Comment: @user3095420 you said you wanted a single chip solution.

Comment: Search for DESAT circuit, or you can replace the MOSFET with some other embedded switch with all protection, look for Infineon HitFET

Comment: Or if you want to stay with International rectifier and TO-220 packaege you have a switch protected to 45A: http://www.irf.com/product-info/datasheets/data/auips1021.pdf

Comment: @MarkoBuršič the intellegent switches seem like a perfect solution! Strange that I have never heard of intelligent low side switches before. how do these "switches" differ from standard MOSFET? for example can the gate of these switches be controled using a PWM?

Comment: @user3095420 I guess, no. They are switches. You didn't mention in your desription that you have PWM, update the answer.

Comment: @MarkoBuršič PWM isn't necessarily required. I was simply asking for future reference :)

Answer (score 2):

A 30A, 2 milli ohm resistor sounds like a challenge to me, but OK, my daily work is in the micro-Amps range :-).

Since you probably don't need high accuracy, how about using the MOSFET's Rds_on resistance for measuring the current ? Look in the datasheet what Vds will be at 30 A and the Vgs you're going to use. For example at 25 degrees, Vgs = 6 V, Id = 30 A Vds will be around 250 mV.

Use a comparator to compare Vds to a reference voltage of for example 400 mV. When Vds > 400 mV switch off the MOSFET. As you switch OFF the MOSFET Vds will increase to 24 V so the comparator will keep the MOSFET off.

Comment: Finding a suitable shunt resistor will not be a problem (lower resistance rated for 30A is possiable). I think a shun is preferable as the resistance will not vary greatly with any flictuatuons in temperature. Comparator idea is fantastic tho!

Comment: I agree that a shunt resistor is more accurate but ask yourself, how much accuracy do you need ? If it is just to protect your devices, you do not need much accuracy. You have to choose the max. Vds such that it is not exceeded when everything is OK including temperature. For a shunt resistor I would place it between source of MOSFET and ground. And use a comparator that can handle this. Some rail-to-rail opamps can handle this for sure.

Answer (score 1):

This might be a bad idea (as stated) for a couple of reasons.

1. If you limit current, you limit the motor's torque. This can prevent the motor starting at all, or starting under heavy load, or cause it to stall in the high current condition when it encounters a temporary load that would otherwise clear.
2. If you simply current limit to some value like 10A, by controlling the gate voltage to partially turn off the FET, you will drop substantial voltage across it (maybe 10V) thus dissipating 100W or so in the FET. Heatsink and cooling arrangements to cope with this will be vastly more expensive than you need. If you really want to limit the operating current, you can shut the current off completely and re-enable it very fast - this is efficient, and is called PWM control.

The motor can tolerate stall current operation for a limited time - otherwise it would destroy itself on starting! (Some traction motors will - unless they are soft-started). So a good control circuit will allow short term operation at high current, then either shut the current off completely before the motor burns out, or limit it via PWM control.

Or are you really protecting the power supply? If so, PWM control works, but limits the available torque as above.

So your block labelled "Some IC" is either a PWM controller, or possibly a microcontroller with PWM and some other logic to allow full current while preventing overload. (You probably also need an INA300 to generate a suitable voltage from the current shunt, for a 2-chip solution).